# Dump file from url with cron job

Tags: python, curl, cron, wget, urllib

I wrote simple Python script with urllib to retrieve file. Everything is working if the file in address owns the ending, lets say .txt, or .exe or .csv. But I got an url with the ending of file like this -- action=download&user=kff&projectname=15&date=today; So as I see it query the data from sql database and dump it in csv format in browser. When I use this link simple in the browser it works perfectly. When I am trying to do it with python it dumps me file with 0 Kb size. Here is the code:

```
import os
import urllib
pp = os.path.join("path", "fileName")
urllib.urlretrieve ("urlLink", pp)
```

Should I use wget instead of that or any other ideas would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its the URL ending and not something different? There is a `user` in the query part of the url, maybe you have to be logged in at that website in order to download data and in your browser you are logged in?

Comment: nope, it works even on fresh installed browser